# Shopify store data in metafields

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I am using unleashed and syncing products from unleashed to shopify.
So is there any way I can trim product description (that is synced from unleashed) and save that trimmed data in custom metafield dynamically?

For now I have tried to and written code in liquid file but that only displays the name and doesn't save anything in metafield

Answer (score 0):

You can only save data in Metafield resources using Admin API calls. You cannot affect data from the front-end.